# Any chance on windows server to see how long TCP port in use?

Tags: windows, powershell

We have some troubles with tons of TPC ports, hanging in TIME_WAIT status on several windows machines. Reboot solves this problem, but I'm just interested in  one more thing. Is there any way to know on windows OS, when TCP port was open or how many days it is in current status? Default -netstat is not showing any interesting info.

Comment: This is a question about the Windows OS itself - voting to move to [sf] as its more suited to general software.

Comment: Oops. Forgot about it. But it's a good decision. Question could be moved or I should post new question at ServerFault?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows PowerShell (but not PowerShell *Core*), on Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012 R2 or above you can find out when a TCP connection was *created*.

<sup>**Note**: The `Get-NetTCPConnection` cmdlet first became available in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012, but creation-time functionality only appears in the 8.1 / 2012R2 docs. **The OP reports that even on 2012R2 it doesn't work**, however. Do tell us if you know more.</sup>

The following command shows all TCP connections in state `TimeWait` (`TIME_WAIT`), in ascending chronological order (oldest one first):

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State TimeWait | Sort-Object CreationTime | 
  Format-Table Local*, Remote*, State, CreationTime
```

If you want to see the results by *time span* (how long ago they were created):

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State TimeWait | Sort-Object CreationTime | 
  Format-Table Local*, Remote*, State, 
               @{ n='Created Ago'; e = { [datetime]::Now - $_.CreationTime } }
```

<sup>Note: Use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table` if you want to process the results *programmatically*. `Format-*` cmdlets are only for *display*.</sup>

However, that won't tell you how long the connections have been *in a given state*.

Comment: on 2012R2 servers `CreationTime` is empty. May be some sort of logging must be enabled fo this?

Comment: That's unfortunate, @UtkaKanibal - I don't know if there's a way to enable it, but my guess is that it's not an option (I don't have access to server machines). The docs suggest that `CreationTime` became available in 2012R2.